# Google Fonts not loading on Bokeh Line Glyph until after interacting with the Glyph

Tags: python, html, bokeh

I'm having an issue with the font incorrectly displaying on my graph until after the user interacts with the graph on my standalone HTML document.

Here's the python code that is used to generate the script and div to place in the HTML file (notice I am using Roboto as my font):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   "B":[5,6,3,2,1,4]})

graph = ColumnDataSource(data= df1)

p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=400)
p.line(source = graph, x = 'A', y = 'B')

p.xaxis.axis_label = "Number"
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font = 'Roboto'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '14pt'
p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '10pt'

p.yaxis.axis_label = "Average"
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font = 'Roboto'
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '14pt'
p.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '10pt'

script, div = components(p)
```

And the following is the html after inserting both the script, div, and the necessary other scripts and links to the header (ie the cdn.bokeh.org and fonts.googleapis):

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Line Plot</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,500,700" />
        <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
                  var fn = function() {
                    Bokeh.safely(function() {
                      (function(root) {
                        function embed_document(root) {

                        var docs_json = '{"acd6be22-a352-429f-bbb6-e0e40d198ca6":{"roots":{"references":[{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"5824","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"5822","type":"ColumnDataSource"}},"id":"5859","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5847","type":"HelpTool"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"ticker":{"id":"5838","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"5841","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"below":[{"id":"5832","type":"LinearAxis"}],"center":[{"id":"5836","type":"Grid"},{"id":"5841","type":"Grid"}],"left":[{"id":"5837","type":"LinearAxis"}],"plot_height":400,"renderers":[{"id":"5858","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"5861","type":"Title"},"toolbar":{"id":"5848","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"5824","type":"DataRange1d"},"x_scale":{"id":"5828","type":"LinearScale"},"y_range":{"id":"5826","type":"DataRange1d"},"y_scale":{"id":"5830","type":"LinearScale"}},"id":"5823","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"#1f77b4","x":{"field":"A"},"y":{"field":"B"}},"id":"5857","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5846","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5833","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"line_color":"#1f77b4","x":{"field":"A"},"y":{"field":"B"}},"id":"5856","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"data":{"A":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"B":[5,6,3,2,1,4],"index":[0,1,2,3,4,5]},"selected":{"id":"5867","type":"Selection"},"selection_policy":{"id":"5868","type":"UnionRenderers"}},"id":"5822","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Average","axis_label_text_font":"Roboto","axis_label_text_font_size":{"value":"14pt"},"formatter":{"id":"5862","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"major_label_text_font_size":{"value":"10pt"},"ticker":{"id":"5838","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"5837","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"5822","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"5856","type":"Line"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"5857","type":"Line"},"selection_glyph":null,"view":{"id":"5859","type":"CDSView"}},"id":"5858","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"5866","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5843","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"5866","type":"BoxAnnotation"}},"id":"5844","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5842","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5867","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5862","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"5826","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5864","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"text":""},"id":"5861","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{"ticker":{"id":"5833","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"5836","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Number","axis_label_text_font":"Roboto","axis_label_text_font_size":{"value":"14pt"},"formatter":{"id":"5864","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"major_label_text_font_size":{"value":"10pt"},"ticker":{"id":"5833","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"5832","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5828","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5838","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5830","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5868","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5845","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_inspect":"auto","active_multi":null,"active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","tools":[{"id":"5842","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"5843","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"5844","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"5845","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"5846","type":"ResetTool"},{"id":"5847","type":"HelpTool"}]},"id":"5848","type":"Toolbar"}],"root_ids":["5823"]},"title":"Bokeh Application","version":"1.4.0"}}';
                        var render_items = [{"docid":"acd6be22-a352-429f-bbb6-e0e40d198ca6","roots":{"5823":"03d9974b-b67c-4395-9dec-d23214a6cb55"}}];
                        root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);

                        }
                        if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                          embed_document(root);
                        } else {
                          var attempts = 0;
                          var timer = setInterval(function(root) {
                            if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                              clearInterval(timer);
                              embed_document(root);
                            } else {
                              attempts++;
                              if (attempts > 100) {
                                clearInterval(timer);
                                console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing");
                              }
                            }
                          }, 10, root)
                        }
                      })(window);
                    });
                  };
                  if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
                  else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
                })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bk-root" id="03d9974b-b67c-4395-9dec-d23214a6cb55" data-root-id="5823"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice the font of the major axis labels, then drag the graph in any direction, you will notice the fonts for the major axis change to Roboto.

I've tried also to use `autoload_static()` method to generate the script, then insert the glyph into the HTML that way however, I end up with the exact same result. There are also no errors in the console on chrome.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had hoped things might fare better with the newer `json_item` API, but that does not work either. As of Bokeh 1.4 I am afraid I don't have any good answer or workaround to suggest. At this point I would characterize this as a bug that requires investigation, so I'd encourage you to [submit a GitHub issue about it](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) (including complete code to reproduce).

Comment: Thanks, I will submit an issue through GitHub.